# How to run a flow between particular time intervals

Tags: power-automate

I was creating one of the automated cloud flows where I want the task to be created in a Planner from an email coming in the Distribution List. I am successfully able to do that, but I need an enhancement where that flow only runs between a particular time frame let's just say only between 14:00 - 18:00 GMT. Please help guide me through it?

I am expecting the flow to run between a particular time frame and process all the emails coming in that time frame as a task in planner.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Furthermore, please clarify your requirements. Do you mean only process emails that arrive within the timeframe or create Tasks for all unprocessed emails within the given timeframe?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look a trigger conditions. You could use a trigger condition on the when an email arrives trigger action which checks if the receiveddatetime field value of the email is between 14:00 and 18:00 hours.